# Smooth scroll within a div

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am creating a small directory with links to scroll to the alphabetical list within a scrollable div. I need to have the contents of the div scroll only not the entire page. I am using Smooth scroll found here:

https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll

This is my code:

```
      $(document).ready(function() {


    $('.quick_links li a').click(function() {
  $.smoothScroll({
    scrollElement: $('#designers_box'),
    scrollTarget: '#designers_box'
  });
  return false;
});

});
```

I know I shouldn't use #designers_box on both arguments but not really understanding the documentation. Is anyone familiar with this?

Here is a link to the work:

http://fourcemag.kenaesthetic.com/homme/index.htm

You will see it is doing something but not quite working yet.
Thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `scrollElement` is **what** is scrolled and your `scrollTarget` is **where** it is scrolled to.

So, this would be my guess:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.quick_links li a').click(function() {
        $.smoothScroll({
            scrollElement: $('#designers_box'),
            scrollTarget: $(this).attr('href')
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Great, now if you could accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: One more quick question. I am trying to add easing to it but it won't accept any others except linear and swing. Why is that?

Comment: I don't know - it uses the [jQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method, so easing should work the same. Are you using the [Easing Plugin](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/quick-tip-add-easing-to-your-animations)?

Comment: I installed jquery ui and it is working thanks. Now I am noticing that the page scrolls down past the header to the directory on load. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: No, I don't know. I'm seeing this error on the page though: `Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'change_parent_url'` on line 11 - don't know if that has something to do with it.

Comment: Hmmm. I do remember that from an earlier attempt to add a login modal window but I removed that a while ago. Where are you seeing this error message. I am looking firebug but not seeing any errors

Comment: On this page: http://fourcemag.kenaesthetic.com/homme/index.htm -- I'm in Chrome and see it on js console of developer tools

Comment: strange because there is nothing on line 11? it is a blank line

Comment: Maybe I'm looking at a cached version

Comment: No I saw it too. I did some hacking arounb and found it was the modernizr script.